# python parsing file into data structure

Tags: python, regex, parsing, data-structures

So I started looking into it, and I haven't found a good way to parse a file following the format I will show you below. I have taken a data structures course, but it doesn't really help me with what I want to do. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**Goal:** Create a tool that can read, create, and manipulate a custom file type

**File Format:** I'm sure there is a name for this type of format, but I couldn't find it. Anyways, the format is subject to some change since the variable names can be added, removed, or changed. Also, after each variable name the data could be one of several different types. Right now the files do not use sub groups, but I want to be prepared in case they decide to change that. The only things I can think of that will remain constant are the GROUP = groupName, END_GROUP = groupName, and the varName = data.

```
GROUP = myGroup
    name1 = String, datenum, number, list, array
    name2 = String, datenum, number, list, array
    // . . .
    name# = String, datenum, number, list, array
    GROUP = mySubGroup
        name1 = String, datenum, number, list, array
    END_GROUP = mySubGroup
    // More names could go here
END_GROUP = myGroup
GROUP = myGroup2
    // etc.
END_GROUP = myGroup2
```

- Strings and dates are enclosed in " (ie "myString")
- Numbers are written as a raw ascii encoded number. They also use the E format if they are large or small (ie 5.023E-6)
- Lists are comma separated and enclosed in parentheses (ie (1,2,3,4) )

**Additional Info:**

- I want to be able to easily read a file and manipulate it as needed. For example, if I read the file and I want to change an attribute of a specific variable within a group I should be able to do something along the lines of dataStructure.groupName.varName = newData.
- It should be easy to create my own file (using a default template that I will make myself or a custom template that has been passed in).
- I want it to treat numbers as numbers and not strings. I should be able to add, subtract, multiply, etc. values within the data structure that are numbers
- The big kicker, I'd like to have this written in vanilla python since our systems have only the most basic modules. It is a huge pain for someone to download another module since they have to create their own virtual environment and import the module to it. This tool should be as system independent as possible

**Initial Attempt:** I was thinking of using a dictionary to organize the data in levels. I do, however, like the idea of using dot structures (like what one would see using MATLAB structures). I wrote a function that will read all the lines of the file and remove the newline characters from each line. From there I want to check for every GROUP = I can find. I would start adding data to that group until I hit an END_GROUP line. Using regular expressions I should be able to parse out the line to determine whether it is a date, number, string, etc.

I am asking this question because I hope to have some insight on things I may be missing. I'd like for this tool to be used long after I've left the dev team which is why I'm trying to do my best to make it as intuitive and easy to use as possible. Thank you all for your help, I really appreciate it! Let me know if you need any more information to help you help me.

EDIT: To clarify what help I need, here are my two main questions I am hoping to answer:

- How should I build a data structure to hold grouped data?
- Is there an accepted algorithm for parsing data like this?

Comment: Are you certain that you cannot use an existing file format for which there are standard Python libraries, such as XML and the ConfigFile format?

Comment: If you want dicts but with dot structures, use `getattr`, `hasattr`, `setattr` builtins to store into an object's dictionary.

Comment: That being said, this looks like a pretty tall order with very little effort on your part to find a solution. You have to either break the question up into much smaller pieces or accept the fact that there is no one good solution as it stands.

Comment: @rd_nielsen: I am certain that I can't use an existing file format. The file format being used has been used for decades now and there are hundreds of thousands of files using that format. I was actually surprised that the format wasn't a standard format used.

Comment: If your use cases allow reading and writing the entire file, you might also consider using the `pickle` library to serialize your data structure.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: It is definitely a large problem. I am hoping to be pointed in the right direction rather than have the answer given to me. I am pretty familiar with Python, but it seems like I always learn something new. My two biggest questions are: How should I build a data structure to hold grouped data? and Is there an accepted algorithm for parsing data like this?

Comment: I already answered part 1. There is no accepted parser for the exact format you specify, but you can always switch to XML, which has a built in parser in Python.

Comment: You also have to be very specific about how you identify the different variable types. Everything is stored as a string in a text file...

Comment: I am looking into using the

      getattr,

      hasattr,

and

      setattr

functions right now. I am also aware that it will be a challenge to manage the different variable types. Because of that, I am trying to be very careful as I begin writing this tool to avoid problems down the road. 
Thank you for your insight!

Comment: @magicbycalvin, is this question still relevant? It might take me time to produce a simple but effective solution for this and I'd need to know whether it would be relevant or not.

Comment: @M.M, this question is still relevant. I would be incredibly happy to see your take on the problem as I have only developed what feels like a hacky solution using a search tree.

Comment: @magicbycalvin, so... I don't have enough time right now, but I'd solve it using a python module for developing grammars, namely [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) which would allow you to specify a recursive grammar and parse files that match it. Consequently, the altering and rewriting of data would have to be done by you, but that is just a matter of iterating the tree recursively and printing (this should be easy). I have used this grammar on a project of my own and I think it was very robust and useful.